# Creating a class that accepts either a double or string in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to program (in Java) what seems like a relatively easy set of requirements but I am having trouble with types. I want to take scientific data from an instrument and put it through some logic to come up with an answer. My problem is that the data will either come off as a string (always "None") or a double. The data set will be two points per sample. So, here are my thoughts: I need class with two parameters that can be either a string or double. So, I decided I would make a class with generic parameters. When it came to performing the logic on the double or string, I had trouble. For example, here are two parts of the logic:

If v < 26 and f is between 36.5 and 37, then sample needs to be rerun.

If v > 31 and f is "None", then rerun.

There are more rules but I won't include them all here, but both v and f may be either a double or "None".

If all the values were doubles I would have no problem, but the fact that I can get doubles or strings is giving me trouble when trying to compare the two. I'm not sure if a generic class is the way to go. Any ideas?

Also, this is my first post so please let me know if you need more information or have any tips on posting.

Thanks!

Comment: Try trying.....

Comment: what exactly is your problem? type check? type casting?

Comment: `"Also, this is my first post so please let me know if you need more information or have any tips on posting."` -- yes, we need to see your attempt and know more about what *specific* problems you might be having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken: Your input type is always String (if it can be `"None"` it is a String). However, it can be a String with numbers and a dot that may be *parsed* as a `Double`.

Something like this should help:

```
public static Double parseInput(String input) {
    try {
        return input.equals("None") ? null : Double.valueOf(input);
    } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
}
```

This returns a null for "None", which seems the most reasonable mapping, and handles anything not a number (blank, null, bad data) by returning the special "not a number" Double value.

Comment: Surely you mean `Double.valueOf(input)`.

Comment: @shmo whatever. Same result, less typing. `valueOf` behaves identically to `new`, except for edge case performance, which is unlikely to be measurable in this situation.

Comment: I would use `Double.valueOf()` for consistency with `Integer.valueOf()`, where it's obviously preferable. Also, even if it currently calls a constructor, using a static method allows for future optimization.

Comment: I would use Double.NaN for not a number and leave the type as `double`.

Comment: @peter surely "None" maps perfectly to null and has that string reserved for that meaning. But I agree that rubbish would more sensibly map to NaN (updated).

Comment: Thanks for all the responses! I looked back at the data and looks like the requirements given were incorrect, the instrument actually outputs "Undetermined", not "None" like I originally thought. That being said, it seems to me that the solution above will still be valid. I'm hoping to try implementing this later today but if not I'll probably work on it Monday. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use String as parameter type, then inside your class you can try to parse the value to double and apply your logic on it if the value can be parsed to double.

If not, then the value is a String and you have to apply the logic of String values

Answer (score 0):

> If all the values were doubles I would have no problem,

Similar to @Bohemian's answer but I would make use of `NaN` and leave the value a primitive.

```
public static double parseInput(String input) {
    return "None".equalsIgnoreCase(input) 
            ? Double.NaN
            : Double.parseDouble(input);
}
```

To check for none use

> If v > 31 and f is "None", then rerun.

```
if (v > 31 && Double.isNaN(f))
```